# Connecting to a database

Tags: c++, sql, oracle

I need to connect to an oracle database, what is the best way of doing so ODBC, ole db, or any others? speed is a bit of an issue and I will be running quite a few statements during runtime, however it would be nice if there's something fairly easy to program, also a tutorial would be helpful too

Comment: If speed's an issue, then use whatever Oracle provides for C++ to talk to the database directly. Anything else will have one or more translation layers which will add overhead and slow things down.

Comment: If speed is an issue than the choice of library won't make a big difference since the overhead of even a thick layer will be tiny compared to a network latency, IO time, and DB overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the original author of [QOpenOCCI](http://qopenocci.sourceforge.net/) (QT, no longer maintained) and under the hood we used [OCILIB](http://orclib.sourceforge.net/). OCILIB did a good job of simplifying the base OCI libraries from Oracle and it was pretty dang fast.

You're biggest overhead will likely be the DB processing layer or the connection to the DB, not the library of choice.

Comment: This looks like what I need, the example codes provided are really helpful, I'm sure the DB processing will be an issue, the program is going to running either locally or over a fibre optic network so i don't think that will be an issue